# How do I combine a string with elements from a SPLITed string?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two cells that I want to reference:

- A category cell (I will call this `1A`)
- A cell with a list of items associated with `1A`

I want to get the list cell separated out as you would with the `SPLIT()` function, but with the `1A` in front of it.

Given that

- *Category* is `1A`, and
- *List* is `List Item 1, List Item 2, List Item 3`

I want my final output to look like this:

```
1A List Item 1
1A List Item 2
1A List Item 3
```

And so on.

Comment: I have formatted your post. Could you check and see if the formatting makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Google Spreadsheet function [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/71291).

I created a [dummy spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/a/auspicious.com.au/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ap5YqZDs3Zh6dDFjWTZPZkk3b0RBcnJoWHFLS0xKNlE#gid=0) where you can see it in action.

I put your data in cell A5, and your list in cell B5
Then in C5 I put

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A5&split(B5,","))
```

Then you get what you are expecting in cell C5, D5 and E5.